# In Polymer, when should styles be inside or outside the template tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

In most cases, the `style` tag is inside the `template` tag for encapsulation. This is one of the best parts of Web Components, so that's unsurprising.

However, in some cases, such as the official Polymer Elements (https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-a11y-announcer/blob/master/iron-a11y-announcer.html), the `style` tag is **outside** the `template` tag. Why is this? When should it be inside and when should it be outside?

Answer (score 3):

This was the recommended way about a year ago for a short while, but they changed the recommandation back to styles inside the `<template>` tag. Not all code has been updated yet and styles outside template works as well, therefore no pressure to change the code.